# Angular ng-class does not effect on other styling

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am using some ng-class to check form validation and add new styling, the problem is when i add class with ng-class innee styling does not work, but in console when adding that class styling is applied

Here is my code

```
<div class="section colm colm6">
    <label for="firstname" class="field prepend-icon" ng-class="{'state-error':goedlevenForm.firstname.$dirty && goedlevenForm.firstname.$invalid}">
       <input type="text" name="firstname" class="gui-input" placeholder="Uw naam..." required>
       <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    </label>
    <em class="state-error" ng-show="goedlevenForm.firstname.$dirty && goedlevenForm.firstname.$invalid">Vul uw naam in</em>
</div>
<!-- end section -->
```

And **CSS**

```
------------------------------------- */
.goedleven .state-error .gui-input,
.goedleven .state-error .gui-textarea,
.goedleven .state-error.select > select,
.goedleven .state-error.select-multiple > select,
.goedleven .state-error input:hover + .checkbox,
.goedleven .state-error input:hover + .radio,
.goedleven .state-error input:focus + .checkbox,
.goedleven .state-error input:focus + .radio,
.goedleven .state-error .checkbox,
.goedleven .state-error .radio {
    background: #FEEFE9;
    border-color: #E46B66;
}

    .goedleven .state-error .field-icon i,
    .goedleven .state-error .gui-textarea ~ .field-icon i {
        color: #e74c3c;
    }

.goedleven .state-error.select .arrow {
    color: #e74c3c;
}

.goedleven .state-error.select:before {
    border-left: 1px solid #E46B66;
}

.goedleven .state-error .gui-input ~ .input-hint,
.goedleven .state-error.file .gui-file:hover + .gui-input,
.goedleven .state-error .gui-textarea ~ .input-hint {
    border-color: #E46B66;
}

.goedleven em.state-error{
    display: block !important;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 0 3px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #CC0000;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}
```

Comment: What a class are you adding?

Comment: state-error class are added

Comment: this is wrong class what did you try else?

Comment: When i add mannualy class state-error all is working nice